# How to limit add to a model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

How to limit add to a model in django ? i would like to create only one company on this model, only one, so if user want to add more, it s not possible.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=250)
```

Comment: This sounds like the "singleton" design pattern. Here is a post about adapting that to a django model: https://steelkiwi.com/blog/practical-application-singleton-design-pattern/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of solutions is to override save method on Company

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=250)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if Company.objects.exists():
            return
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but your question is rather short and not precise so that's probably not the way you want it to behave

Comment: the idea is to have only one company, one record only, i will try this option, or if you have any other recommandation

Comment: Can you explain how it does not work? code is pretty straightforward -> if there exist a row in company database -> skip new instance saving. Its hard for it to not work

Comment: just try it again, it shows like it s valid and msg is that the company saved but when i check on db it doesn't. also on template. the msg that is saved confused me

Comment: Understandable. When you dig more into django you will notice that the messages displayed are usually "delegated" when model form is proved to be valid. In this case the form for second instance is valid so the message is set to be shown in with response and also model ```save()``` method is invoked but due to its override, it will basically do nothing so no new instance will be created.